# c sharp encoding (hebrew)

Tags: mysql, .net, encoding, hebrew

I am getting Hebrew data from mySql database. The data is in Hebrew.
I am receiving the following string

÷øéú éí

I know it's hebrew, but I can't encode it in a right way..

here is my code:

```
Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8");
Encoding sourceEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

byte[] sourceBytes = sourceEncoding.GetBytes(myReader.GetString(1));
byte[] hebrewBytes = Encoding.Convert(sourceEncoding, hebrewEncoding, sourceBytes);

string hebrewString = hebrewEncoding.GetString(hebrewBytes);
```

The output of this code is "aae ci", while it should be "אבי חן"

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Get rid of all conversions; you should not need them.  What is the destination -- a web page, console, another file, what?  Provide `SELECT HEX(col) ...` for a snippet of the garbled data.

Comment: If you have to specify an encoding, something is wrong. .NET strings are Unicode. MySQL allows you to store Unicode strings if you specify the UTF8 encoding. You shouldn't have to specify any encoding.

Comment: If the column's encoding is *not* UTF8, you should change it to UTF8. It's far too easy to mix up encodings - in fact, your code is converting from one non-Unicode encoding to another - why? That's **guaranteed** to mangle characters, as there are no Hebrew characters in Latin1

Comment: Even if your table is using a Hebrew codepage, you should be able to read data without conversion. If it's *not* using Hebrew or UTF8, you have a problem. If you store data using the wrong codepage, some of them will end up wrong or even lost. Is that why you are trying to read Hebrew data as Latin1 here? Someone stored the data to a Latin1 column?